# Using htaccess in Apache to block query string input

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have been staring at this for a while not I can't fathom it, probably a wood for the trees scenario.

I am attempting to use HTACCESS to block certain inputs to a web server, so I have added the following directives:

```
#######################################
## QUERY STRING / HTTP METHOD BLOCKS ##
#######################################
# request query string contains /proc/self/environ
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} proc\/self\/environ [NC,OR]
#request query string contains base64_encode / base64_decode
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_(en|de)code[^(]*\([^)]*\) [NC,OR]
# Block <script> in query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [NC,OR]
# Prevent use of specified methods in HTTP Request 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD|TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC,OR] 
# Block out use of illegal or unsafe characters in the HTTP Request 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*(\\r|\\n|%0A|%0D).* [NC,OR] 
# Block out use of illegal or unsafe characters in the Referer Variable of the HTTP Request 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)(<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR] 
# Block out use of illegal or unsafe characters in any cookie associated with the HTTP Request 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*(<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR] 
# Block out use of illegal characters in URI or use of malformed URI 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(,|;|:|<|>|">|"<|/|\\\.\.\\).{0,9999}.* [NC,OR] 
# Block out  use of illegal or unsafe characters in the User Agent variable 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR] 
# Measures to block out  SQL injection attacks 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(;|<|>|'|"|\)|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update|md5|benchmark).* [NC,OR] 
# Block out  reference to localhost/loopback/127.0.0.1 in the Query String 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1).* [NC,OR] 
# Block out  use of illegal or unsafe characters in the Query String variable 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

After adding this I was expecting that if I opened the following URL:

- http://www.mysite.com/page.php?var=localhost
- http://www.mysite.com/page.php?var=drop

I would get a 403 error back, however all I am seeing is page.php.  Conclusion is that the directives are malformed and not being followed.

Could anybody offer any guidance on where I may have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify RewriteEngine On and that you have properly set it up to parse the htaccess file. Check your errorlogs for clues. If you make a simple rewrite that is not working, it probably did not load your htaccess. Try putting them in a httpd.conf and run httpd -S to syntax check. Gotta be sure rewrites are working first, then you can fix any regex misses.

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing a kind of web application firewall, using RewriteRules is rather limited. I'd recommend using [mod_security](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/tree/v2/master) and an [existing ruleset](https://owasp.org/www-project-modsecurity-core-rule-set/).